# RHEL Crontab can't execute command

Tags: linux, shell

Crontab isn't executing this command

```
*/1 * * * *  /usr/bin/top -u user -n 1 | /bin/grep -v grep | /bin/grep java | /usr/bin/head -n 1 | /bin/awk '{if ($9 >  100) print $1, $9}' | /bin/cut -d'm' -f2  >> /etc/file.log
```

Can you please advise ?

Comment: This is a question for the unix forum...but I assume you want execute this every minute so (* * * * *) and not /1. Another hint. A lot of pipe's (|), I think is better put this on a shell script

Answer (score 0):

Try:

replace `>>` by `2>&1 >>`:

```
*/1 * * * *  /usr/bin/top -u user -n 1 | /bin/grep -v grep | /bin/grep java | /usr/bin/head -n 1 | /bin/awk '{if ($9 >  100) print $1, $9}' | /bin/cut -d'm' -f2  2>&1 >> /etc/file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better served by moving those commands into a shell-script and executing the shell-script from cron:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/etc/do-top-grep
```

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/top -u user -n 1 | \
    /bin/grep -v grep | \
    /bin/grep java | \
    /usr/bin/head -n 1 | \
    /bin/awk '{if ($9 >  100) print $1, $9}' | \
    /bin/cut -d'm' -f2  2>&1 >> /etc/file.log
```

Note: I incorporated the suggestion to use '2>&1 >>` from JCRC's answer.

Comment: PS, this is really the wrong forum for this kind of question.  It would be better in Unix&Linux or Super User.

Comment: Firstly, I added it to script .. and it was working if executed manually .. but can't run from crontab .. the script or the command...that's is making me crazy, I will give a try to your answer and validate it shorlty

Comment: make sure you `chmod +x /the/script` to make it executable as a command

Comment: Please look at my new update here, issue is resolved by using -b as an option for top command instead of others.

Answer (score 0):

-b is the only accepted option by crontab for top command..

so when I put top -b, it works fine.